# Use time values for x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some climate data with temperature and humidity as well as a timestamp which is transformed to the time in `%H:%M`.

When using ggplot2 for visualization, the time gets sorted - screwing the order of measurements as the first measurement was taken at 14:00 (2pm) and the last one at 10:27 (10:27am) the following day.

How do I prevent ggplot2 from sorting the x-values? (see plot)

MVE:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = read_csv('./climate_stats_incl_time.csv')
colnames(df)[1] <- c('sample')
head(df)
tail(df)


ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=time)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=temperature, color='red')) +
    geom_line(aes(y=humidity, color='blue'))
```

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  sample   timestamp temperature humidity time  
   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <drtn>
1      0 1581253210.        21.9     47.6 14:00 
2      1 1581253275.        21.7     47.8 14:01 
3      2 1581253336.        21.7     47.8 14:02 
4      3 1581253397.        21.8     47.8 14:03 
5      4 1581253457.        21.7     47.8 14:04 
6      5 1581253520.        21.8     47.8 14:05 

> tail(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  sample   timestamp temperature humidity time  
   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <drtn>
1   1203 1581326567.        19.1     49.8 10:22 
2   1204 1581326628.        19.1     49.7 10:23 
3   1205 1581326688.        19.1     49.9 10:24 
4   1206 1581326749.        19.1     49.9 10:25 
5   1207 1581326812.        19.1     49.7 10:26 
6   1208 1581326873.        19.1     49.8 10:27
```

[image: Plot with sorted x-values.]

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the "day" information in your  `timestamp` column? My advice is not to try to avoid ggplot2 sorting behaviour but instead to clean your times data so they fit the requirement for an easy manipulation

Comment: @Paul indeed, formatting the timestamp worked and I can keep the ggplot2 sorting

Answer (score 1):

Format your timestamps to a proper date-time (assuming the origin is 1970):

```
df$date_time <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
```

Then use this new `date_time` variable instead of `time` for plotting

## Edit:

I accidentally submitted a wrong solution (I re-formated the date-time to a date) . Now the solution should work for your problem (i.e. it makes a date-**time**!)

Answer (score -1):

A workaround

```
df %>%
    mutate(orig_seq = seq(1,nrow(df),1)) %>%
    ggplot(mapping=aes(x=reorder(time, orig_seq)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=temperature, color='red')) +
    geom_line(aes(y=humidity, color='blue'))
```